# Crontab doesn't seem to work

Tags: server, scripts, cron, minecraft, gnu-screen

I run my minecraft server in a screen and I have a script set up to restart the server via `crontab` every night at 3 am.

`restart.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Letting people know that the server is going to restart...."
screen -R mc -X stuff "say Server is restarting in 1 minute! $(printf '\r')"
sleep 30s
screen -R mc -X stuff "say Server is restarting in 30 seconds! $(printf '\r')"
sleep 20s
screen -R mc -X stuff "say Server is restarting in 10 seconds! $(printf '\r')"
sleep 5s
screen -R mc -X stuff "say Server is restarting in 5 seconds! $(printf '\r')"
sleep 1s
screen -R mc -X stuff "say Server is restarting in 4 seconds! $(printf '\r')"
sleep 1s
screen -R mc -X stuff "say Server is restarting in 3 seconds! $(printf '\r')"
sleep 1s
screen -R mc -X stuff "say Server is restarting in 2 seconds! $(printf '\r')"
sleep 1s
screen -R mc -X stuff "say Server is restarting in 1 second! $(printf '\r')"
sleep 1s
screen -R mc -X stuff "stop $(printf '\r')"
sleep 15s
screen -R mc -X stuff "bash start.sh $(printf '\r')"
echo "Done"
```

This code works perfectly when I run it myself. It sends all the messages in the chat and then restarts but no matter how hard I wish, `crontab` just will not run it.

This is the code I have in the minecraft users `crontab`:

```
0 3 * * * /home/minecraft/server/restart.sh
```

Comment: Back to basics: Is restart.sh executable?

Comment: have you restarted cron service? Have you tried to set it work every minute? Make one echo in a file at start `echo something > /your/path/file`

Comment: `$ ./restart` 
`Letting people know that the server is going to restart....
./restart: 3: screen: not found
./restart: 5: screen: not found`

Comment: Maybe there're errors with your `screen -R mc -X stuff` command when you run it using cron, but cron does not show them.

Comment: @Gryu this is because you don't have a screen named "mc" like i do, if you create a screen called "mc" and try running it again it should not give these errors

Comment: @user535733 yes the script is an executable, ive tested running it myself

Comment: The `cron` environment differs from your terminal environment. Run `(echo "=== set ===";set;echo "===env ==="; env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias)` in each, and compare.

Comment: @waltinator where do i run this?

Comment: always use full excutable file path in scripts that have to be scheduled with cron

Comment: maybe ```-xX``` works

Comment: Put this line in your `crrontab`: `*  *  *   *   *     (echo "=== set ===";set;echo "===env ==="; env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias) >cron.environment`. Wait 3 minutes, then remove it. Then, in your terminal: (echo "=== set ===";set;echo "===env ==="; env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias) >term.environment`. Compare the two files with `diff {cron,term}.environment`